# How to stream music to mobile devices over the web?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile

I am creating a website for a local band. I am just starting to learn web development, so I offered to do it for free(As long as they pay for the hosting and domain name). Because they are a band, they obviously want to have their music on their website. For the main, desktop site, I just added an html5 plugin, which works perfectly on a desktop. Today, i wanted to start on a mobile  version or the website, and i also want to play music on it. The problem is, is that the plugin that I used on the desktop site doesn't seem to work on mobile devices.

So are there any specific plugins that work on phones, and iPods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/) worked great for me (on Android, desktop, iPhone etc.) - Installation guide [here](http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation). (Sorry but I can't say anything about iPod but don't think its a problem)